# Hebrew or Arabic typesetting problem in Indesign

Tags: arabic, adobe-indesign, hebrew

I want to know how the right-to-left language of the Middle East language is set in Indesign.
As Below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g5cL.png)

If I use spaces between numbers and characters, the numbers will be ranked elsewhere
So I used 'i' replacing space，Then set i to colorless,but i konw that not a good idea,if there have a Arabic friends，Can you tell me the correct way?

Comment: Hello Xiaoqin - I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to directly involve code, nor tools used primarily for programming. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You may have a greater chance of getting an answer to your question over at [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). It has similar questions tagged under [indesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign). However, before posting there please read their FAQ section to ensure it complies.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe products like InDesign and Illustrator, and I believe even Photoshop have an option to be installed with a different regional settings.
See [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/access-install-hebrew-arabic-indesign-illustrator-CC.html).
Then you would have access to what is called "World Ready Paragraph Composer" under Type menu and in the Paragraph Panel which is what is controlling the right-to-left paragraph direction.